# s1 == s2 evaluates to false when both of the string values are "1.25"

Tags: c#

I had an odd problem earlier today. I was comparing two strings, and the `==` operator was evaluating to `false`. The `s1.Equals(s2)` function would evaluate to `true`.

What caused this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show short but complete program demonstrating your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably compared with the wrong operator overload: `operator == (object a, object b)` instead of `operator == (string a, string b)`.

The default `==` operator checks for reference equality, but if both operands are expressions of `string` type, then the `string` overload is used, and it compares for string equality.

If one of the operands is *not* of `string` type, then the compiler will choose the `operator == (object a, object b)` overload.

The following code will reproduce the problem:

```
object a = "foo";
object b = "FOO".ToLowerInvariant(); // Avoid string interning
Console.WriteLine(a == b); // False
```

This code makes sure to create two identical strings which are not reference equal. If I used `"foo"` as the value of `b`, both objects would point to the same reference, and the reference equality comparison would happen to return `true`.